# read and write tfrecords binary file (type missmatch)

Tags: image-processing, binary, tensorflow

Hi I'm trying to build an image input pipe. My preprocessed training data is stored in a tfrecords file which I've create with the following lines of codes:

```
def _bytes_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

def _int64_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))
```

..

```
img_raw = img.tostring()                                        # typeof(img) = np.Array with shape (50, 80) dtype float64
img_label_text_raw = str.encode(img_lable)
example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
    'height': _int64_feature(height),                           #heigth (integer)
    'width': _int64_feature(width),                             #width (integer)
    'depth': _int64_feature(depth),                             #num of rgb channels (integer)
    'image_data': _bytes_feature(img_raw),                      #raw image data (byte string)
    'label_text': _bytes_feature(img_label_text_raw),           #raw image_lable_text (byte string)
    'lable': _int64_feature(lable_txt_to_int[img_lable])}))     #label index (integer)

writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
```

Now I try to read the binary data to reconstruct a tensor out of it:

```
def read_and_decode(filename_queue):
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)

    features = tf.parse_single_example(
        serialized_example,
        # Defaults are not specified since both keys are required.
        features={
            'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'height': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'width': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'depth': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'image_data': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
        })

    label = features['label']
    height = tf.cast(features['height'], tf.int64)
    width = tf.cast(features['width'], tf.int64)
    depth = tf.cast(features['depth'], tf.int64)

    image_shape = tf.pack([height, width, depth])
    image = tf.decode_raw(features['image_data'], tf.float64)
    image = tf.reshape(image, image_shape)


    images, labels = tf.train.shuffle_batch([image, label],     batch_size=2,
                                                 capacity=30,
                                                 num_threads=1,
                                                 min_after_dequeue=10)
    return images, labels
```

Sadly this is not working. I get this error messag:

> ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype string for Tensor with
>   dtype int64: 'Tensor("ParseSingleExample/Squeeze_label:0", shape=(),
>   dtype=int64)' 
>   ...
>
> TypeError: Input 'bytes' of 'DecodeRaw' Op has type int64 that does not match expected type of string.

Can some give me a hint on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**: complete code listing of "read_and_decode"

@mmry thank you very much. now my code breaks at shuffeling the batch. With:

> ValueError: All shapes must be fully defined:
>   [TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(None), Dimension(None)]),
>   TensorShape([])]

any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, you have serialized the `label_text` in your tfrecords. Then how do you parse this data in the decoder? Could you please give some advice? Thanks.

Comment: record_iterator = tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator(path=<FILE_NAME>)

for string_record in record_iterator:
    example = tf.train.Example()
    example.ParseFromString(string_record)

    label_txt = (example.features.feature['label_text'].bytes_list
                  .value[0].decode("utf-8"))

Comment: the example above will iterate through all data elements an decode the lable string

Comment: thanks a lot for your comment!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to use the `tf.decode_raw()` op in this line:

```
label = tf.decode_raw(features['label'], tf.int64)
```

Instead, you should be able to write:

```
label = features['label']
```

The [`tf.decode_raw()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/io_ops/converting#decode_raw) op only accepts `tf.string` tensors, and converts the binary representation of some tensor data (as a variable-length string) into a typed representation (as a vector of a particular type of elements). However, you have defined the feature `'label'` as having type `tf.int64`, so there is no need to convert that feature if you want to use it as a `tf.int64`.

Comment: I think the problem here is that each of your images can be a different size (according to the `'height'`, `'width'`, and `'depth'` features). To use `tf.train.shuffle_batch()`, you must resize the images so that they all have the exact same size, e.g. using an image-processing op like [`tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/image/cropping#resize_image_with_crop_or_pad). If all of the images in the input *do* have the same size, you can pass that size as a constant (e.g. `[299, 299, 3]`) to `tf.reshape()` and `tf.train.shuffle_batch()` will work.

Comment: yeah that did it! all the images have the same size so a passed a fixed number! I originally included the size in the training set that I reconstruct the picture if i need to